# ng-pick-datetime's styling is out of place

Tags: css, angular, typescript, datepicker

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why the arrow is super big? I didn't implement any custom stylings and what not..

Comment: Hi ! Did you inspect the element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was picking up this project from another team.
Just realized that the "picker.min.css" that they are referencing is from "src/assets/styles/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css", which, for some reason, is outdated?

I copied "picker.min.css" from "node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css" and replace the one stored in "assets".

And the way the css is referenced is in "index.html":

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css">
```